# How can objects communicate without violating the Dependency Inversion Principle?

Tags: python, oop, dependency-inversion

I am building a Path Planner that will help people plan a path through an RPG console game.

I want to create a table that shows each step through the stage. I have actually [implemented a working version of this](http://pastebin.com/jajXPj7Y), however, it is seemingly awful OOP design; it breaks all sorts of principles, and I believe it is not even legitimate OOP. **The problem is, clearly, that `Table` is a God Class.**

Due to this, I have decided to rewrite it while trying to keep in mind proper OOP principles. I want to break up `Table` into multiple classes.

**My problem is I need various objects to talk to each other.** However, my solution is to always use **composition**. This breaks the dependency principle as well as the single responsibility principle.

Here is the main Table that will store the player's steps:

```
class PathTable(object):
    ''' A path table. '''

    def __init__(self):
    # table is a list of dicts, representing rows
        self._table = []

    @property
    def table(self):
        return self._table

    def addStep(self, step):
        ''' Adds a step to the table. '''
        self._table.append(step)

    def rmStep(self):
        ''' Removes the last step from the table. '''
        try:
            del self._table[-1]
        except:
            raise IndexError('Tried to remove item from an empty table.')
```

Now, I have created an `InputManager` that is responsible for accepting and validating user input:

```
class InputManager(object):
    ''' Responsible for managing user input. '''
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def addFight(self, position):
        ''' Add a 'fight' at table[position]. '''
        # table._table[position]['input'] = 'fight'
        # Need to somehow edit a particular row in the Table.
```

However, now I do not know how I can access `PathTable._table[position]`. Without breaking all kinds of OO design principles.

It is frustrating, because the entire job of `InputManager` is to access `PathTable`. But I cannot use composition to place `InputManager` inside `PathTable`, because it is bad design.

**What is a clean way to accomplish this?**

*I am a beginner, and I am trying to learn.*

Comment: Why not add a `getStep` method to `PathTable`? Also the contents of `rmStep` can just be replaced with `self._table.pop()`

Comment: "My problem is I need various objects to talk to each other" => looks like a candidate for a Mediator http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern

Answer (score 1):

First add support for editing a step's row in your `PathTable` class:

```
class PathTable(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._table = []

    ## NB : This defeats the whole point of making `_table` private
    #@property
    #def table(self):
    #    return self._table

    def add_step(self, step):
        ''' Adds a step to the table. '''
        self._table.append(step)

    def rm_step(self):
        ''' Removes the last step from the table. '''
        return self._table.pop()

    def update_step(self, position, key, value):
        self._table[position][key] = value
```

Then pass a `PathTable` instance to your `InputManager`:

```
class InputManager(object):
    ''' Responsible for managing user input. '''
    def __init__(self, path_table):
        self._path_table = path_table

    def add_fight(self, position):
        ''' Add a 'fight' at table[position]. '''
        self._path_table.update_step(position, 'input', 'fight')
```

Comment: Is it ok to so this, because now InputManager depends on PathTable?

Comment: How could a mediator or controller (that's mostly what your `InputManager` is) not depend on the objects it has to work with ?  But if you reread the code, `InputManager` doesn't depend on the `PathTable` *class*, it just expects to be initialized with an object exposing the same (implicit) interface as `PathTable`. FWIW, having UI layer objects depending on domain model layer objects is expected - how else could they do their job ? -, what you don't want is having the domain model layer depending on the UI layer.